# segfault in fwrite on linux

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fwrite

I have  a piece of C code where I try to write a buffer into an opened output file.I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to run the code.

```
if (fwrite(header, record_size, 1, uOutfile) != 1)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The header is a properly populated and I am able to print out the contents of the header.the size of the buffer header is definitely greater than the record_size.Is there anything else worth checking.?Any other reason where fwrite can cause a segfault.Gdbing the problem gave the following output

```
0x00007ffff6b7d66d in _IO_fwrite (buf=0x726d60, size=16, count=1, fp=0x738820) at iofwrite.c:43
43  iofwrite.c: No such file or directory.
    in iofwrite.c
```

it seems to suggest that the output file has not been created.how ever and ls -l on my directory shows the output file of size 0 bytes.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could throw some light on the problem.

EDIT: Code that opens the file:

```
outfd = open(out, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0664);
if (outfd == -1) {
    dagutil_panic("Could not open %s for writing.\n", out);
}
uOutfile = fdopen(outfd, "w");
```

Comment: Please add the code that opens the file.

Comment: outfd = open(out, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0664);
             if (outfd == -1)
     {
        dagutil_panic("Could not open %s for writing.\n", out);
     }
     uOutfile = fdopen(outfd, "w");

Comment: "it seems to suggest that the output file has not been created" ← are you sure about that? It suggests to me that `gdb` can't find your source code — unless you're outputting a .c file.

Comment: I meant add it to the question.

Comment: @Thanatos: the iofwrite.c file is part of glibc, this is the file that contains the fwrite implementation, so it is expected that he won't have the sources for that file. What I would like to see is the entire stack trace, not just the line for the crash.

Comment: @Miguel Grinberg: Ah, my bad. I agree — we need to see the real stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's enough here to know for sure what your problems are, but here are some thoughts:

- Show us the code involving your `FILE *` (`uOutFile`) and your buffer (`header`) — we can then see if you're borking memory somewhere between.
- Run your code through `valgrind`: You're getting a segfault, so it could probably catch what you're doing wrong.
- In `gdb`, examine the contents of both `header` and `uOutFile` (not just the pointer, but the pointed-to-memory.) (You'll have to use some smarts to figure out if `uOutFile` looks right, but you should be able to up-or-down determine if `header` is correct.)

To add to this: my general debug strategy when I get segfaults is:

1. `gdb`'s backtrace. Tells me *where* the segfault happened. Usually, this is enough to uncover the dumb thing I did.
2. Look at the pointers in the vincinity of the crash. Is the pointer correct, and is the pointed-to data correct? (esp. if you see something strange like `0xdeadbeef`)
3. Valgrind Valgrind Valgrind

(2 & 3 are in no particular order.)